# How to split xts OHLC data by the specified number of candles

Tags: r, xts

I have candle data

```
len <- 10000
times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), length = len, by = "sec")
prices <- cumsum(rnorm(len))+1000

library(xts)
xp <- xts(x = prices,order.by = times)
xp <- to.minutes5(xp)

xp

xp.Open   xp.High   xp.Low xp.Close
2016-01-01 00:04:59 1001.8097 1004.7440 986.8783 986.8783
2016-01-01 00:09:59  986.7830  995.0656 960.4920 966.7475
2016-01-01 00:14:59  965.9071  979.9402 965.2857 975.6030
2016-01-01 00:19:59  973.5659  988.7293 965.7774 983.4846
2016-01-01 00:24:59  982.7731  982.7731 945.9951 946.5125
2016-01-01 00:29:59  946.3951  949.1420 925.5131 936.8539
2016-01-01 00:34:59  935.7039  954.8570 935.7039 948.0653
2016-01-01 00:39:59  949.0397  951.8483 928.8650 942.4658
2016-01-01 00:44:59  943.3805  963.3857 939.1387 947.9653
```

..

```
chart_Series(xp)
```

[image]

I can change chart periods with the function `to.period()` at selected times.

But how can I just change the chart period according to the number of candles I set?
For example, I want to turn this segment into five candles

something like this

```
n <- 5  # set n candles

breaks <- seq(1, nrow(xp), length.out = n+1)
abline(v=breaks,col=4,lty=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to.minutes` with the desired number of minutes where `xp` is as in the question.

```
to.minutes(xp, 25)
```